# Does Castle project DynamicProxy heavily use Reflection?

Tags: c#, castle, dynamic-proxy

Does Castle project DynamicProxy heavily use Reflection ... like constantly?

Or does it do up front reflection cache the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't use Reflection at all as soon as the instance of the proxy class is instantiated.
It just creates a derived class at runtime. To create that class, it might need to use reflection, but once the class is created, it is just like any other class.